# SQL database not populating via Java by using execute/addBatch

Tags: java, jdbc, batch-processing

I currently have a very large file which contains a few million lines of entries, and want them inserted into a database. The connection established from java to SQL works as I have tried inserting the data singularly and it works, however, when I switched to using `executeBatch` and `addBatch`, it seems to loop though but not populating anything into my database.

Code is as follows:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DatabaseMetaData;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class fedOrganiser6 {
    private static String directory = "C:\\Users\\x\\Desktop\\Files\\";
    private static String file = "combined.fed";
    private static String mapperValue = "";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Connection conn = null;

        try {
            BufferedReader mapper = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(directory + file));
            String dbURL = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\\SQLExpress;database=TIMESTAMP_ORGANISER;integratedSecurity=true";
            String user = "sa";
            String pass = "password";
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, user, pass);
            if (conn != null) {
                DatabaseMetaData dm = (DatabaseMetaData) conn.getMetaData();
                System.out.println("Driver name: " + dm.getDriverName());
                System.out.println("Driver version: " + dm.getDriverVersion());
                System.out.println("Product name: " + dm.getDatabaseProductName());
                System.out.println("Product version: " + dm.getDatabaseProductVersion());
                System.out.println("clearing database");
                conn.createStatement().executeUpdate("truncate table TimestampsStorage");
                System.out.println("bulk insert into database");
                System.out.println("complete");
                int i = 0;
                int records = 0;
                String query = "INSERT INTO TimestampsStorage " + "values(" + "'" + mapperValue.toString() + "'"+ ")";
                conn.prepareStatement(query);
                for (mapperValue = mapper.readLine(); mapperValue != null; mapperValue = mapper.readLine()) {
                    i++;
                    records++;
                    System.out.println("Batching " + records + " records...");

                    conn.createStatement().addBatch(query);
                    if (i == 100000) {
                        conn.createStatement().executeBatch();
                        i = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
            conn.createStatement().executeBatch();
            conn.createStatement().close();
            System.out.print("Done");

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (conn != null && !conn.isClosed()) {
                    conn.close();
                }
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`createStatement()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#createStatement--) creates a new statement object, so you're execute a different statement than the one you're batching on. You should create the `PreparedStatement` once, add several batches to it, and then execute on the same object:

```
String query = "INSERT INTO TimestampsStorage VALUES (?)";
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);
for (mapperValue = mapper.readLine(); 
     mapperValue != null; 
     mapperValue = mapper.readLine()) {

    i++;
    records++;
    System.out.println("Batching " + records + " records...");

    ps.setString(1, mapperValue);
    ps.addBatch();

    if (i == 100000) {
        ps.executeBatch();
        i = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you are throwing away the prepared statement

```
String query = "INSERT INTO TimestampsStorage VALUES (?)";
                PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(query);
                for (mapperValue = mapper.readLine(); mapperValue != null; mapperValue = mapper.readLine()) {
                    i++;
                    records++;
                    System.out.println("Batching " + records + " records...");
                    statement.setString(1,mapperValue);
                    statement.addBatch();
                    if (i == 100000) {
                        statement.executeBatch();
                        i = 0;
                    }
```

Comment: There is no `addBatch(String query)`, for a `PreparedStatment`, only `addBatch()`.

Comment: Still wrong. You need to pass an index to `setString()`. @Mureinik has the correct way to do this.

Comment: I lied, @tim. `PreparedStatement` inherits `addBatch(String query)` from `Statement`. But when you've got the same query that you are just changing parameters for, @Mureinik's solution is the one to use.

Comment: @AndrewMairose  `addBatch(String)` on a `PreparedStatement` (and `CallableStatement`) must throw an `SQLException` (and if it doesn't the driver is not complying with JDBC)

Answer (score 2):

I think you are a bit mistaken on how batch processing for JDBC works.

You are creating a new `Statement` each time you call `conn.createStatement()`.

Instead, you will want to use a `PreparedStatement`. First, change your query to include a `?` where you want your values to go.

```
String query = "INSERT INTO TimestampsStorage VALUES(?)";
```

Then, when you call `conn.prepareStatement(query)`, store the returned `PreparedStatement`.

```
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);
```

This `PreparedStatement` will then 'remember' your query, and you can simply change the values you want where the `?` is on each iteration of your loop.

```
ps.setString(1, mapperValue);
```

The `setString` method will take your `mapperValue` and use it instead of the first `?` it finds in your query (since you pass in the index 1).

Then, instead of calling `conn.createStatement().addBatch()`, you would call `ps.addBatch()`.

Then, outside of your loop, you can call `ps.executeBatch()`. (There is no need to call this inside your loop, so you can remove your `if (i == 100000)` condition).

Finally, if you are using Java 7+, you can use a try with resources, so that you don't need to worry about closing the `PreparedStatement` or `Connection` in a finally block.

Here is what your end result should look like.

```
String query = "INSERT INTO TimestampsStorage VALUES (?)";

try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, user, pass); PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query);) {
    for (mapperValue = mapper.readLine(); mapperValue != null; mapperValue = mapper.readLine()) {            
        records++;

        ps.setString(1, mapperValue);
        ps.addBatch();
    }
    System.out.println("Executing batch of " + records + " records...");
    ps.executeBatch();
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    //handle exception
}
```